# Php, Xdebug bug?

Tags: php

All I have is this, in the very beginning of a script:

```
xdebug_stop_code_coverage(true);
xdebug_start_code_coverage();
var_dump (xdebug_get_code_coverage());die;
```

another things already run of course (Im using framework), but this should return an empty string - it does not! It returns this file, and two other files which codes had already run.